# How does one construct a proper embedding (Topology)?

Tags: general-topology

I have a hard time with constructing embeddings. Could someone explain/give a hint on how to do the following example?

Give an example of an embedding $i: S^1 \to T$ of a circle into the torus, such that $T\setminus i(S^1)$ is not connected.

I get what an embedding is, I just simply have no idea where to start with constructing one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon) of the torus. You know which side is attached to which side. Now can you draw a circle on this polygon that divides $T$ into more than one components?

Comment: This has helped a lot, thank you!